# The period of a function is not just the inverse of the frequency of a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, physics

I am getting a strange result. I have a periodic function $x(t) = 3cos(4t)+2sin(6t)+cos(10t)$. I worked out that the period is $\pi$, but I also worked out that the frequency of the function is 60 hertz. This doesn't make any sense because the frequency should just be $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. What's wrong?

$2\pi/4,2\pi/6,2\pi/10$ are the periods, so the least common multiple is $\pi$. On the other hand, $4\pi,5\pi,10\pi$ are the frequencies so the least common multiple is $60\pi$.

Comment: I'm a lil lost in your arithmetics: as the title of the OP implies $f=\frac{1}{T}$ where $T$ is the period and $f$ the frequency. So, how on earth do you get the $4,5,10$ frequencies ?

Comment: @KonKan My mistake, multiply those values by 2pi

Comment: The frequency of the total function is not the least common multiple of the frequencies, it is their greatest common factor.

Comment: @Rahul I see, that is where I am going wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that the period is $T=\pi$. Thus we have the frequency: $f=\frac{1}{\pi}$ and the angular frequency: $\omega=2\pi f=\frac{2\pi}{T}=2$.

Here is the graph:

[image: $x(t) = 3cos(4t)+2sin(6t)+cos(10t)$]

also: the functions $cos(4t)$, $sin(6t)$, $cos(10t)$ have 
$$
\begin{array}{l|ccc}
 & cos(4t) & sin(6t) & cos(10t) \\ \hline
\omega=2\pi f = \frac{2\pi}{T} & 4 & 6  & 10 \\ 
f=\frac{1}{T} & \frac{2}{\pi} & \frac{3}{\pi} & \frac{5}{\pi} \\ 
T & \frac{\pi}{2} & \frac{\pi}{3} & \frac{\pi}{5} \\ 
\end{array}
$$
correspondingly.

Comment: I don't understand, how are they not 60*pi?

Comment: Are you saying that the frequency of a graph is not the least common multiple of these periodic function's frequency?

Comment: yes, that is what i'm saying!

Comment: I see, so that is where my mistake is

Comment: yes, it has already been mentioned in a comment on the OP.